# SwiftUI Binding Data

Tags: swiftui

trying to bring data from LeadDetailUI to formUI to be able to edit the data in formUI and for the life of me can't figure this out, not sure on way to go (Bindings or environmentObject). eighthor way can't get it to work. I tried with bindings couldn't get it to work. please help with example on how to do this.

```
struct LeadDetailUI: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: getCustomerData

    @State var tbl11 = ""
    @State var tbl12 = ""
    @State var tbl13 = ""
    @State var tbl14 = ""
    @State var tbl15 = ""
    @State var tbl16 = ""
    @State var tbl17 = ""
    @State var tbl21 = ""
    @State var tbl22 = 0
    @State var tbl23 = 0
    @State var tbl24 = 0
    @State var tbl25 = 0
    @State var tbl26 = ""
    @State var tbl27 = ""
    @State var l11 = ""
    @State var l12 = ""
    @State var l13 = ""
    @State var l14 = ""
    @State var l15 = ""
    @State var l16 = ""
    @State var l17 = ""
    @State var l21 = ""
    @State var l22 = ""
    @State var l23 = ""
    @State var l24 = ""
    @State var l25 = ""
    @State var l26 = ""
    @State var l27 = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack() {
                
                ScrollView(self.height > 700 ? .init() : .vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 13) {
                        HStack {
                            TextField("Peter Balsamo", text: $name).font(.title)
                                .padding(.top, 3)
                                .padding(.leading, 20)
                                .padding(.bottom, -10)
                            //.redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                            
                            Text("Following").font(.headline)
                                .padding(.top, 10)
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                                    .padding(.top, 7)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 15)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Divider()
                        
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5, content: {
                                    
                                    TextField("Amount", text: $amount).font(.largeTitle)
                                        .offset(y: -3)
                                    TextField("Address", text: $address).font(.title3)
                                    TextField("City", text: $city).font(.title3)
                                    
                                    TextField("Sale Date:", text: $l1datetext).font(.caption2)
                                        .padding(.top, 15)
                                    TextField("Date:", text: $date).font(.headline)
                                        .padding(.top, -5)
                                    
                                    
                                })
                                .padding(.bottom, 0)
                                .padding(.leading, 15)
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0, content: {
                                    
                                    Image("taylor_swift_profile")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 115, height: 115)
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                                        .padding(.top, -25)
                                    
                                    TextField("Lead#", text: $id).font(.caption2)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                        .padding(.top, 15)
                                })
                                .frame(width: 120)
                                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
                                    HStack {
                                        Toggle("", isOn: $showingSold.animation(.spring()))
                                            .frame(width:80, height: 30)
                                            .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .blue))
                                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                        
                                        if showingSold {
                                            Text("Priority").font(.headline)
                                                .background(Color.red.cornerRadius(10))
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .padding(.leading, 10)
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                
                                Spacer()
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    showFullscreen.toggle()
                                }) {
                                    Text("Map")
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .frame(width:115, height: 30)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                }
                                
                                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                                
                            }
                            .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        }
                        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showFullscreen, content: {
                            HomeMap()
                        })
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(self.color == 0 ? Color.black : Color.white)
                    .background(self.color == 0 ? Color.yellow : Color.purple)
                    .clipShape(CustomShape(corner: .bottomLeft, radii: 55))
                    
                    ScrollView(self.height > 800 ? .init() : .vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        
                        let first = DataUI(name: tbl11, label: l11)
                        let second = DataUI(name: tbl12, label: l12)
                        let third = DataUI(name: tbl13, label: l13)
                        let fourth = DataUI(name: tbl14, label: l14)
                        let fifth = DataUI(name: tbl15, label: l15)
                        let sixth = DataUI(name: tbl16, label: l16)
                        let seventh = DataUI(name: tbl17, label: l17)
                        let eighth = DataUI(name: tbl21, label: l21)
                        let ninth = DataUI(name: "\(tbl22)", label: l22)
                        let tenth = DataUI(name: "\(tbl23)", label: l23)
                        let eleven = DataUI(name: "\(tbl24)", label: l24)
                        let twelve = DataUI(name: "\(tbl25)", label: l25)
                        let thirteen = DataUI(name: tbl26, label: l26)
                        let fourteen = DataUI(name: tbl27, label: l27)
                        
                        let customers = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, tenth, eleven, twelve,thirteen, fourteen]
                        
                        List(customers) { customer in
                            CenterViewUI(formData: customer)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .statusBar(hidden: true)
                    .animation(.default)
                    
                    BottomViewUI(comments: self.$comments, lnewsTitle: self.$lnewsTitle, index: $index)
                }
                .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Profile")
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems (
                leading:
                    Button(action: {
                        showActionSheet.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    },
                trailing:
                    //NavigationLink(destination: FormUI(frm11: $tbl11)) {
                    Button(action: {
                        showSheet.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Edit")
                            
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet, content: getActionSheet)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                FormUI()
            })
            .foregroundColor(self.color == 0 ? Color.yellow : Color.purple)
        }
    }

struct DataUI: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var label : String
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            LeadDetailUI(viewModel: getCustomerData())
                .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
}  





public struct FormUI: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: getCustomerData
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
   
    @State var frm11 = ""
    @State var frm12 = ""
    @State var frm13 = ""
    @State var frm14 = ""
    @State var frm15 = ""
    @State var frm16 = ""
    @State var frm17 = ""
    @State var frm18 = ""
    @State var frm19 = ""

    
    public var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollView(self.height > 800 ? .init() : .vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack {
                        
                        //ForEach(self.viewModel.data) { i in
                            
                            Form {
                                Section {
                                    HStack{
                                        VStack{
                                            Image("taylor_swift_profile")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                                                .padding()
                                            
                                            Button(action: {}, label: {
                                                Text("Edit")
                                                    .font(.caption)
                                                    .padding(.top, -15)
                                                    .foregroundColor(self.color == 0 ? Color.purple : Color.red)
                                            })
                                        }
                                        .padding(.leading, -30)
                                        Divider()
                                        Spacer()
                                        VStack(spacing: 12) {
                                            TextField("First", text: $frm11)
                                            TextField("Last", text: $frm12)
                                            Picker(selection: $selection, label:
                                                    TextField("Company", text: $callback)) {
                                                ForEach(0 ..< pickContractor.count) {
                                                    Text(self.pickContractor[$0])
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .font(.system(size: 20.0))
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    }
                                }
                                .font(.headline)
                                .padding(.leading, 18)
                                
                                Section(header: Text("Customer Info")) {
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Address:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("address", text: $address)
                                            .formStyle()
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("City:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("city", text: $city)
                                            .formStyle()
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("State:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("state", text: $state)
                                            .formStyle()
                                            .frame(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: 60)
                                            .autocapitalization(.allCharacters)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                            //.padding(.leading, )
                                        Spacer()
                                        Text("Zip:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        TextField("zip", text: $zip)
                                            .formStyle()
                                            .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 145)
                                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Phone:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("phone", text: $phone)
                                            .formStyle()
                                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Amount:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        Stepper(
                                            onIncrement: {
                                                stepperValue += 1000
                                            },
                                            onDecrement: {
                                                stepperValue -= 1000
                                            },
                                            label: {
                                                TextField("amount",  text: $amount)
                                                    .formStyle()

                                            })
                                            
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Email:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("email", text: $email)
                                            .formStyle()
                                            .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                Section {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Salesman:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("salesman", text: $salesman)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Job:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("job", text: $jobName)
                                            .formStyle()
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Product:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("product", text: $adName)
                                            .formStyle()
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Quantity:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("quantity", text: $frm25)
                                            .formStyle()
                                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Apt Date:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        DatePicker(selection: $selDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                                            TextField("", text: $aptdate)
                                                .formStyle()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Comments:")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextEditor(text: $comment)
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                Section(header: Text("Misc")) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
                                            Text("\(self.isOn == true ? "Active":"Not Active")")
                                                .formTextStyle()
                                        }
                                        .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: .purple))
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Date")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        DatePicker(selection: $selDate, displayedComponents: .date, label: {
                                            TextField("", text: $date)
                                        })
                                    }
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Spouse")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("spouse", text: $spouse)
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Called Back")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        Picker(selection: $selection, label:
                                                TextField("", text: $callback)) {
                                            ForEach(0 ..< callbackPicker.count) {
                                                Text(self.callbackPicker[$0])
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        
                                        Text("Rate")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        Picker(selection: $selection, label:
                                                TextField("", text: $rate)) {
                                            ForEach(0 ..< pickRate.count) {
                                                Text(verbatim: self.pickRate[$0])
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Photo")
                                            .formTextStyle()
                                        Spacer()
                                        TextField("photo", text: $photo)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .font(.system(size: 20.0))
                            .padding(.top, -40)
                            

                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Data Entry")
            
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle").font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                       //if !frm11.isEmpty && !frm12.isEmpty {
                            saveData()
                            resetTextFields()
                            self.alert.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Save")
        
                }
                
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $alert) {
                
                Alert(title: Text("Upload Complete"), message: Text("Successfully updated the data"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
            }
        }
        .accentColor(self.color == 0 ? Color.purple : Color.red)
    }
    
    private func saveData() {
        
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
        ref = db.collection("Customers").addDocument(data: [
            "active": frm30,
            "custId": frm12,
            "custNo": custNo,
            "leadNo": leadNo,
            "first": frm11,
            "lastname": frm12,
            "contractor": frm13,
            "city": city,
            "state": state,
            "zip": zip,
            "phone": phone,
            "amount": Int(amount) as Any,
            "email": email,
            "rate": rate,
            "salesNo": saleNo,
            "jobNo": jobNo,
            "adNo": adNo,
            "quan": Int(frm25) as Any,
            "start": NSNull(),
            "completion": NSNull(),
            "lastUpdate": Timestamp(date: Date()),
            "creationDate": Timestamp(date: Date()),
            "aptdate": aptdate,
            "comments": comment,
            "spouse": spouse,
            "photo": photo,
            "uid": uid,
        ]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error adding document: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateData() {
        
        db.collection("Customer")
            .document()
            .setData(["active":self.frm30,"custId":self.frm12,"custNo":self.custNo,"leadNo":self.leadNo,"first":self.frm11,"lastname":self.frm12,"contractor":self.frm13,"city":self.city,"state":self.state,"zip":self.zip,"phone":self.phone,"amount":self.amount,"email":self.email,"rate":self.rate,"salesNo":self.saleNo,"jobNo":self.jobNo,"adNo":self.adNo,"start":self.start,"lastUpdate":Timestamp(date:Date()),"aptdate":self.aptdate,"comments":self.comment,"spouse":self.spouse,"photo":self.photo]) { (error) in
                
                if error != nil{
                    
                    print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                    return
                }
                //self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
    }
}

struct FormUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormUI()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's crazy number of states in one view... I'm not even sure if SwiftUI engine would handle this correctly.

Comment: what is all this State for? which work your app is doing or will doing?

Comment: Try using some arrays instead of all these variables.

Comment: it worked, ill put it in a array then see if it solves my issue